# Excel COM object ignores print area

Tags: python, excel, printing, com

When one opens Excel workbook with Excel COM object

```
app = gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
doc = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
```

all print areas are dropped, but they're accessible via VBA when the file is opened normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localized versions of MS Excel ignore print areas and titles when accessed as a COM object, so one must explicitly specify `PageSetup.PrintArea|PrintTitleColumns|PrintTitleRows` for each worksheet if needed.

```
for sh in self.doc.Worksheets: #explicitly specify print areas and titles
    for name in sh.Names:
        if name.Name.endswith("!Print_Area"):
            sh.PageSetup.PrintArea = name.RefersTo
        elif name.Name.endswith("!Print_Titles"):
            #protect comma symbol in sheet name
            chunks = name.RefersTo.replace(sheet.Name, "[sheet_name]").split(",")
            chunks = [i.replace("[sheet_name]", sheet.Name) for i in chunks]
            if len(chunks) == 1:
                try: sh.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns = chunks[0]
                except: sh.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = chunks[0]
            else: sh.PageSetup.PrintTitleColumns, sh.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = chunks
```

[Source: Excel -> PDF (ExportAsFixedFormat)](http://prog.hu/tudastar/181452/excel-pdf-exportasfixedformat)

UPD: Support sheet names with commas